# Opening SMS editor from web application

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios, windows-phone

I'm looking for a solution which allows me to open native SMS editor from web-page. Body of the message has to be prepopulated and receiver's phone number has to be empty.

There are plenty of suggestions here in stackoverflow to just format anchor or redirect via javascript but unfortunately these solutions are outdated and either do not work as is or are stripped for security reasons.

I've tested following formats on various platforms, but unfortunately they don't work on all devices. I'm looking for an universal solution or library to fulfill the requirements I mentioned.

```
<a href="sms:;body=Hello world">Send SMS</a>
<a href="sms:;body=Hello%20world">Send SMS</a>
```

Used to work on IOS devices but doesn't work anymore. Apparently pre-filled body only works if you supply a phone number which you have in your contacts.

```
<a href="sms:?body=Hello world">Send SMS</a>
<a href="sms:?body=Hello%20world">Send SMS</a>
```

Works on most android devices. Opens up SMS editor, but only some versions allow prepopulated body.

Windows Phone doesn't seem to do anything.

I'm starting to wonder if this is just an endless swamp of compability issues. Technology which the web application is built-on is ASP.NET MVC 5.

Answer (score 8):

100% working

// for andriod

```
if(navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)){
            
    window.open('sms://1900/?body=encodeURIComponent('sms body......'),'_blank')
      
}
```

// for IOS

```
if(navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)){
           
 window.open('sms://1900/&body=encodeURIComponent('sms body......'),'_blank')
  
}
```

replace 1900 with the number you want to send message

Body = sms body

credit goes to :- https://codepen.io/gil--/pen/KMaRmp

Comment: Thank you, this really helped my PWA.  I used it without default message.     if(navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)){    
      window.open('sms://'+phoneNumber);      
     }

    if(navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)){     
      window.open('sms://'+phoneNumber);
      }

Answer (score 4):

This works on iOS 8 (verified):

```
<p>Open <a href="#" id="myLink">SMS</a>.</p>
<script>
    $('#myLink').click(function () {
        window.open('sms:&body=My%20text%20for%20iOS%208', '_self');
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

This *should* works on iOS 5,6:

```
<p>Open <a href="#" id="myLink">SMS</a>.</p>
<script>
    $('#myLink').click(function () {
        window.open('sms:;body=My%20text%20for%20iOS%205', '_self');
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Notice `sms:&` for iOS 8, `sms:;` for iOS 5,6 (and `sms:?` for Android).

Remember to encode the text after `body=`

Source: [julianklotz](http://blog.julianklotz.de/2015/03/14/the-sms-uri-scheme/)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to populate the body but not the phone number this works for both android and IOS8+

thisisthelink

the key is: "sms:?&"

Answer (score 0):

you can open it with

```
window.open('sms:+1111111111')
```

it opens messaging app and ready to write something for that number

note:Tested in Android

Answer (score -1):

It's not possible to add text, you can only add phone numbers so that

```
<a href="sms:+12345678901">sms link</a>
```

opens the messaging app.

Apps can register for custom protocol schemes to be called, when a request with such a url was made. But as far as I understand your solution is a pure web application, so the answer is no, it's not possible.